# How would I copy a cell based on multiple cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Morning all, I have a question I'm hoping someone can help me with a formula for. I'm trying to return a value from Sheet2 into Sheet1 based on two different criteria. For example:

Sheet1:

| Lvl | Amount | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | $ | 001 |
| 2B | $ | 002 |
| 2C | $ | 003 |
| 1B | $ | 001 |

Sheet2:

| Lvl | 001 | 002 | 003 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | $300 | $275 | $250 |
| 1B | $200 | $175 | $150 |
| 1C | $100 | $75 | $50 |
| 2A | $350 | $325 | $315 |
| 2B | $250 | $225 | $210 |
| 2C | $150 | $125 | $110 |

So on Sheet1, if the first column value matches the Sheet2 first column value, then return the value in that row for the correct ID. The completed would be:

Sheet1 (completed):

| Lvl | Amount | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | $300 | 001 |
| 2B | $225 | 002 |
| 2C | $110 | 003 |
| 1B | $200 | 001 |

I'm stumped on how to do a multiple lookup like this though and on what formula would go in Sheet1 in the Amount column. Also, I can't use VBA as it is blocked by my company.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `HLOOKUP` and `MATCH`.

`=HLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!$A:$D,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0))`

`MATCH` will return the row index of the Lvl that you are looking for. `HLOOKUP` needs the row index to look in, and it will use the ID number as C2 to find that in the table columns.